# Find all "critical nodes" in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Say there is a graph in which every node is connected to every other by some path. 
How would i find the particular nodes, which if removed would lead to some of the nodes NOT being connected to all the other points?

I think DFS needs to be used. But i don't undertsand how.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to find cut vertices in a connected graph. This is a common problem, eg. see See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/